# Используя regex вытащить слова из 4 букв, в которых есть буква a или o

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из строки, `String s = "fkjvl dfof dsag aaafg"`. Выделить только "dfof" и "dsag". Первое, что пришло в голову, использовать `regex`. Придумал, что-то вроде такого, но работает на словах, в которых более 4 символов, как исправить? `(\b(\w*[ao]+\w*)\b)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?=\b\w{4}\b)\w*[oa]\w*
```

Можно использовать позитивный просмотр вперед, выделив любые 4 буквы или цифры или символ нижнего подчеркивания, так как `\w` эквивалентно `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
После провести валидацию всех найденных четырех-символьных слов на наличие букв `o` или `a`
В случае, если это обязательно должны быть только буквы, то `\w` нужно заменить на `[a-zA-Z]`

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/E96LeJ/1)